# Intuitive explanation of Fourier series existing for periodic functions

Tags: continuity, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, periodic-functions

'Any periodic function which follows Dirichlet's conditions can be expressed as a Fourier series.'

Is there any mathematical proof to validate this? Even if not a proof per se, how to convince oneself intuitively of this statement? I did read about Fourier experimentally arriving at the series from the heat equation, but how did he ascertain that any periodic function which follows certain criteria (Dirichlet's conditions) can be expressed as one such series.

I understand it is true, but is there any way to actually believe this intuitively?

As in, just looking at a square wave which is periodic, how do I ascertain that it is made up of innumerable sine and cosine waves?

Am quite interested to know about this.

Comment: Fourier proved it.

Comment: Think about bases in vector spaces. Starting with $R^2$, any vector can be represent as a sum of two orthogonal vectors $e_1= <1,0>$ and $e_2=<0,1>$. Similarly (though there is a huge abstraction jump here) $L^2[0,1]$ is a vector space and one has concept of orthogonality there (i.e. function f is orthogonal to g if $\int_0^1 fg dt = 0$). Hence, one would like to know if  any function can be represented as a sum of orthogonal functions. The most natural set of orthogonal functions are $e^{2\pi nt}$.

Comment: If it were intuitive in the time of Fourier, then Fourier would not have been banned from publishing his treatise on the subject, and others would have believed.